# How can send silent Push notification for android device without knowing to the user (in background) .?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ngcordova

In the `APNS` Push Notification ,we have option called **content_available** using this we can send Push Notification to the application that will work in background and update the app without interaction of Users.
Same thing I have to do in android how can i do this

I am implementing this application using ngcordova with angular js

Comment: Don't show the notification and using intent update the app (if already open)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing when implementing push notifications in an android application.

When you implement your own GCM broadcast receiver you can perform actions in the background.

If it is a small and insignificant change, as push notifications usually are (with only max of 8 kb of data) you can implement the code in the [onReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method of the broadcast receiver. **BUT THAT IS A BAD PRACTICE.**

The correct practice would be to extend the [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), create a custom IntentService and start it with the **startWakefulService** method from your extended WakefulBroadcastReceiver's onReceive method, passing the received intent.

**Edit:**
After some reading, according the [new google GCM API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), instead of using WakefulBroadcastReceiver and an extended IntentService, you should use [GcmReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmReceiver) (which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver) and [GcmListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService) (which extends Service).
The behaviour remains the same, with the exception of getting the message already processed and extracted in [onMessageReceived](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService.html#onMessageReceived(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) instead of doing so yourself yourself in [onHandleIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)).

Comment: hi can any help in this part i am working on hybrid application using  ngcordova with angularjs and to send push notification i am using WebApi Not having idea on android. if i want to make any changes in the server side from web api or in the script i can do is there any way to fix this through webapi or script part

Comment: i am using this ngcordova push notification link to receive notification    http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/  i think  in this plugin i have to write WakefulBroadcastReceiver  any one can give idea how to implement this

Comment: try this tutorial:
http://www.pubnub.com/blog/sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/

Comment: i saw the example, it working fine but my requirement is if i am closed that application and if I am increasing the room temperature in the website then i am receiving push notification in the status bar but i need like this if i am increase temperature then i have to send a notification but  that i have hide from the user then do the process in the background.  without knowing to the user (without interaction of user i have to update that temperature in the background)